# Where I can find a repository for an old version of Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I am using raring and just noticed that I can't install packages any more (404). I checked a couple repositories and raring is not there. Turns out it's been EOL'd, at barely 10 months old, it seems a bit harsh.

Is there some way I can avoid an entire reinstall? I really don't want to go through the whole thing of setting up the desktop again, etc. It doesn't matter if the repository isn't being maintained any more, I just want to grab a couple packages. Can I do a dist-upgrade without a ton of stuff breaking?

I just switched over from Debian six months ago, and I am pretty shocked that they expect me to upgrade. Why do some version have no scheduled EOL date? (Ref https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)

To the person that closed this post, this question is time relevant and an answer that is more than 3 years old doesn't necessarily help. Both the articles linked in that post are 404 or way out of date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular Ubuntu releases have a support cycle of 9 months. If you prefer a longer supported time, use the LTS releases. At this moment of writing, the most recent version (14.04 Trusty) is an LTS version.

Upgrades from 13.04 (Raring) to 14.04 is not supported. The suggested upgrade path is:

- 13.04 (Raring) -> 13.10 (Saucy)
- 13.10 (Saucy) -> 14.04 (Trusty)

If you were hitting an LTS version, then you could immediately jump to the next version. So, if you were using 11.10 (Oneiric), then you could follow this path:

- 11.10 (Oneiric) -> 12.04 (Precise, LTS)
- 12.04 (Precise, LTS) -> 14.04 (Saucy, LTS)

As the regular archives do not hold the unsupported packages anymore, you have to change your mirrors to http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/. See also:

- [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/91815/6969)
- [How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/110477/6969)
- [EOL Upgrades - Ubuntu Community Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades/)